# Whitespace Inserted When Using BitConverter

Tags: c#, byte, ascii, bitconverter

I am having the problem that whitespace of some sort is being inserted between characters when I am converting a `Queue<byte>` list into a string for comparison. I do not think that they are actual whitespace characters, however, because the Queue retains only seven values and when debugging I am still able to see the seven character values. See image:

[image]

Relevant code:

```
Queue<byte> bufKeyword = new Queue<byte>(7);

    // Remove old byte from queue and add new one
    if (bufKeyword.Count == 7) bufKeyword.Dequeue();
    bufKeyword.Enqueue((byte)fsInput.ReadByte());

    // Check buffer string for match
    StringBuilder bufKeywordString = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (byte qByte in bufKeyword) { 
        bufKeywordString.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(qByte))); 
    }

    string _bufKeywordString = bufKeywordString.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", _bufKeywordString); //DEBUG - SEE IMAGE

    StringBuilder bufWriteString = new StringBuilder();
    if (_bufKeywordString.StartsWith("time=")) //Does not work because of 'whitespace'
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) { bufWriteString.Append(fsInput.ReadByte()); }     // Read next 24 bytes
        fileWriteQueue.Enqueue(bufWriteString.ToString());                              // Add this data to write queue
        fileWriteQueueCount++;
        fileBytesRead += 24;                                                            // Change to new spot in file
    }
```

Comment: Looks like it's UTF-16, not Ascii.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `BitConverter.GetBytes` for `byte` argument. `byte` gets converted to `short`, and `BitConverter.GetBytes(short)` returns an array of two elements.

So instead of

```
bufKeywordString.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(qByte)));
```

try

```
bufKeywordString.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] {qByte});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I see now that I mistook the return type for the argument type.